# why does the html div not change even though the JS inserting content into the div has changed (and view source shows new JS)?

Tags: javascript, html, browser, browser-cache

### edit:

I've isolated the problem to the JS lib's use of local storage, which on a browser refresh restores the content from local storage wiping out new content changes (fine for production but not dev); original problem is stated below.

### The problem:

I'm working on a html file and a JS file; the JS inserts content into the html div. I change what the JS file inserts and refresh the html, but the browser page div doesn't change. However, when I look at the page source and open the JS file from there, I **do** see the changes I made to the JS.

**So it seems like the browser is loading the new JS. But the content div doesn't change.**

- Here is the JS, http://pastebin.com/NteJmUPz
- And here is the html, http://pastebin.com/G8EBdAbQ

### What I've tried:

I've tried emptying the cache, turning off cache in Chrome dev tools, hard refresh and clear cache in Chrome while dev tools is open, etcetera. Behavior is the same in Chrome and FF.

Even closing and reopening the browser (FF) doesn't work to show the new changes.

### What works:

The one thing that does seem to show new changes is opening a new incognito tab in Chrome. But then I'm back to the same behavior and need to close and open the incognito tab to show changes.

Comment: The second pastebin has been removed. Can you make a smaller example of what you're doing, and a demo at jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Thanks Barmar, I've fixed the paste link. I'll see what I can do with a fiddle, unfortunately it's a third party lib so I'm not sure how much I can pare it down.

Comment: The problem you're describing is that you originally wrote the JS to insert `X` into the DIV. Then you modified the JS to insert `Y`. But when you load the page, it still inserts `X`?

Comment: Could you tell us what part of the JS you changed?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not having success with the fiddle (it doesn't show the div content at all, here http://jsfiddle.net/BdWvf/ ). The JS that changes is the var `squiffy.story.sections`. And yes, you understand the question perfectly @Barmar.

Comment: I don't know how we can tell from here why something you change on your site isn't taking effect. If you see the updated version in the Developer Tools, then it's not caching.

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint at the point in the code where it inserts into the DIV, to see where it's getting the data from?

Comment: You're calling `squiffle.story.begin()` before you assign `squiffy.story.start` and `squiffle.story.sections`.

Comment: I set a breakpoint but wasn't able to trace the dataflow as I'm still just too unfamiliar with this lib; calling `begin()` after assigning to `sections` has no effect unfortunately.

Comment: Thank you @Barmar for your comments, it made me think and I've isolated the problem to the lib's use of local storage.